# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to Javascript. I tried to execute the function cs_sort_directory after the page has been loaded. I get the error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

```
window.onload = cs_sort_directory("http://sample.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", "http://sample.org/wp-content/themes/directory-theme", "alphabetical", this);
```

What did I do wrong?

Here is the function cs_sort_directory:

```
function cs_sort_directory(admin_url,theme_url,sortType,obj){

var node_id = jQuery(obj).parents('.main-filter').data('node');
var form_id = jQuery(obj).parents('.main-filter').data('form');
jQuery(obj).parents('.main-filter').addClass('slide-loader');
jQuery(obj).parents('.cs-filter-menu').children('li').removeClass('active');
jQuery(obj).parents('li').addClass('active');
jQuery('#cs_sort_value').val(sortType);
jQuery(".ajax-loading").html('<i class="icon-spinner8 icon-spin"></i>').fadeIn();
var dataString = jQuery('#directory-filters-form').serialize() + "&sort=" + sortType+"&node_id=" + node_id;

jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: admin_url,
    data: dataString,
    success:function(response){     

        if(response.match('session_destroyed') )  {
            jQuery(".ajax-loading").html('');
            jQuery(obj).parents('.main-filter').append(response);   
        } else {
            jQuery(obj).parents('.dynamic-listing').children('.cs-listing-wrapper').html(response);
            jQuery(".ajax-loading").html('');   
            jQuery(obj).parents('.main-filter').removeClass('slide-loader');
        }
    }
});
//return false;
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that's triggering the error?

Comment: And also, this seems wrong. Unless it returns a function this won't work and you would need to wrap this in an anonymous `function`

Comment: Are you *sure* that this is the offending line? Maybe you missed a closing `)` on a previous line?

Comment: code of  cs_sort_directory please!

Comment: Yes I actually did the quotes before.

Comment: added the function cs_sort_directory!

Comment: This code executes without an error. The problem should be elsewhere. can you post the error stack trace ?